# Flutter Run Command Cause Error "Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain"

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am getting This Error While Running `Flutter Run` Command

```
PS D:\Projects ;)\untitled\android> flutter run 
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider
enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
`Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             380ms
`Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`
```

How to Fix this error ?

I tried to run the gradlew command
`gradlew`
i am getting this error

```
PS D:\Projects ;)\untitled\android> gradlew
gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is   
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gradlew
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gradlew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

Suggestion [3,General]: The command gradlew was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, 
instead type: ".\gradlew". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```